# sequence monad query in clojure

Tags: clojure, monads

I am trying to wrap my head around the sequence monad in query.

I have this code that creates a sequence monad using clojure.algo.monads:

```
(use 'clojure.algo.monads)

(def sequence-monad-decider
     (fn [step-value monadic-continuation]
       (mapcat monadic-continuation step-value)))

(def sequence-monad-monadifier list)

(def sequence-monad
     (monad [m-result sequence-monad-monadifier
             m-bind sequence-monad-decider]))

(prn
 (with-monad sequence-monad
   (domonad [a [1 2]
             b [10, 100]
             c [-1 1]]
            (* a b c))))
```

So I understand that m-bind will be used to pass a step value and a continuation to `sequence-monad-decider`.

`sequence.monad-decider` is defined like this:

```
(def sequence-monad-decider
     (fn [step-value monadic-continuation]
       (mapcat monadic-continuation step-value)))
```

so if we look at calling the monad:

```
(prn
 (with-monad sequence-monad
   (domonad [a [1 2]
             b [10, 100]
             c [-1 1]]
            (* a b c))))
```

With binding `a` of the above, `[1 2]` will be passed as the step value to `sequence.monad.decider` but what is the `monadic-continuation` function that is passed as the second argument to this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More typical names for `sequence-monad-decider` and `sequence-monad-monadifier` are `bind` and either `result`, `return`, or `unit`.

```
(defn bind [mv f] (mapcat f mv)) 
(defn unit [v] [v])
```

Then

```
 (domonad sequence-m
   [a [1 2]
    b [10, 100]
    c [-1 1]]
   (* a b c))
```

Is

```
 (bind [1 2] 
       (fn [a] 
         (domonad sequence-m
           [b [10, 100]
            c [-1 1]]
           (* a b c))))
```

Try it! So, the second argument, which you have aptly named as `monadic-continuation`, is the continuation of the monad, the rest of the action.

If you carried this out, you would unwind completely with

```
(bind [1 2]
      (fn [a] (bind [10 100]
                    (fn [b] (bind [-1 1]
                                  (fn [c] (unit (* a b c))))))))
```

The `domonad` is just sugar. You can see a very simple implementation [at my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21763329/1756702).